# How to know if attribute is used for sortby or not from product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

`Backend > Edit Product attribute > Frontend Properties > Used for Sorting in Product Listing => Yes` allows products to sort by product attribute.

I'm building another view in product listing in tabular form, so while printing the products attributes and values, how can i know if the attribute is used for sorting or not ?

I'm getting products attributes as

```
<?php foreach ($_item->getAttributes() as $_attribute):
     if ($_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1): ?>
       <th>
          <?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel(); ?>
          <!--/ Right here i want to know if this attribute is used for sorting or not from backend with sort url-->
      </th>
<?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following function **getUsedForSortBy** in your code.

```
<?php foreach ($_item->getAttributes() as $_attribute):
 if ($_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1) || $_attribute->getUsedForSortBy() == 1): ?>
   <th>
      <?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel(); ?>
      <!--/ Right here i want to know if this attribute is used for sorting or not from backend -->
  </th>
```

Now you can get the attributes which user can sort.

Comment: it's not the solution but this `$_attribute->getUsedForSortBy() == 1` helped me somehow. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: that just let the attribute used for filter to enter into my condition, but i wanted to know is if the printed attribute label `$_attribute->getStoreLabel();` is used for sort or not

Comment: Cooool Then.. :)

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood that, `$_attribute->getUsedForSortBy()` is what i was i was looking for . Thanks. But what i haven't understand is if i made a single attribute sortable as well comparable in fronted it doesn't get inside `$_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1` on my if condition above. :( i can't take if is sortable attribute as well via or condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_attribute->getIsSortable(); ?>
```

Comment: And url to sort ?

Comment: Didn't understand. You want to know if the attribute is sort-able or not, right? Please clarify about URL to sort.

Comment: actually your code doesn't work. `if($_attribute->getIsSorable()){echo 'is a sortable attribute';}` is false.